# include file with preprocessor define

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, include-path

I want to include a file and use a preprocessor definition for the path.

```cpp
// in projects preprocessor definitions:    
HEADER="../somePath/theHeader.h"

// in a file
#include HEADER
```

This works on Windows but XCode complains about this and can't find the file. Replacing `HEADER` with the path works, so the file actually exists. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Enough quotes, probably.  On Unix, you'd need:

```
HEADER = "../somePath/theHeader.h"

${CC} ${CFLAGS} -DHEADER='${HEADER}' -c file.cpp
```

The macro definition includes double quotes.  If you don't wrap the `-DHEADER` argument in single quotes, the shell (un)helpfully strips off the double quotes.  By putting it inside single quotes, the shell helpfully removes the single quotes leaving the double quotes for the compiler to see.

The rules for command line processing are different on Windows and quotes are handled differently with the `cmd.exe` processor.

Incidentally, when I want to make it feasible for a human to specify the value for `HEADER` on the command line, I use:

```
HEADER = ../somePath/theHeader.h

${CC} ${CFLAGS} -DHEADER='"${HEADER}"' -c file.cpp
```

Now I can run:

```
make HEADER=/other/path/to/header.h file.o
```

and it works.  With the original notation, I'd have to write:

```
make HEADER='"/other/path/to/header.h"' file.o
```

or something similar, which is fiddlier, and doubly awkward if you want to use a command output to specify the file name.  Compare the first option with the second:

```
make HEADER=$(locate header.h)
make HEADER="\"$(locate header.h)\""
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the preprocessor to insert the quotes, which might be less hassle: `#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)` / `#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x` / `#include STRINGIFY(HEADER)`

Comment: That's true; I hadn't needed to use that, but it should work fine. And, as you say, it sidesteps quotes on the command line, which is helpful.

Comment: @rici Your blurb deserves to be an answer.